# Removing days in loop php

Tags: php, date

I have this simple PHP code

```
$date_start = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
$date_end = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59");
$i = 0;
while($i < 900):
    print_r($date_start);
    $i++;
    $date_start = date($date_start, strtotime("-$i days"));
    $date_end = date($date_end, strtotime("-$i days"));
    print_r($date_start);
    echo $i."<br>"; 
endwhile;
```

I would like to get date today then, yesterday, then the date before that and so on. I have tried several variations of this, but I can't seem to be able to get it to work. Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, please have a look on the below code it may help you.

```
<?php

 $i = 0;
 $date_start = date('Y-m-d');
 while($i < 10):
 $days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$i days", strtotime($date_start)));
 $i++;
 echo $days_ago;
 echo "<p></p>";
 endwhile;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $i = 0;
 while($i < 900):
        $i++;
        $date_start = date("Y-m-d  00:00:00", strtotime("-$i days"));
        $date_end = date("Y-m-d  23:59:59", strtotime("-$i days"));
        echo $i." ".$date_start." ".$date_end."\n";
 endwhile;
```